# SetOnKeyListener for TextInput in Kotlin is not working

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to do something for a textInput type number when the "Done" button is clicked. I can setup the textInput fine 'cause I don't get any error but as soon as I press the "Done" key, nothing happens.

Here is my code:

```
private fun setManualQrKeyListener(view: View?) {
        Log.i("TAG", "SETUP")
        view!!.textInput_qr.setOnKeyListener(View.OnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->
            if (event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                Log.i("TAG", "ENTERED")
                if(textView_class.text == "0") {
                    Log.i("TAG", textView_class.text.toString())
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Please classify the vehicle", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    false
                }
                if(view.textInput_qr.length() != 10) {
                    Log.i("TAG", textView_class.text.length.toString())
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Please check the QR number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    false
                }else{
                    Log.i("TAG", textView_class.text.toString())
                    decodeQR(view.textInput_qr.text.toString().trim())
                    true
                }
                true
            }
            false
        })
    }
```

this is in my XML. I used the `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` because in my soft key it says `next` and not `done`

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/editText_qr"
                        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:hint="Manual QR Code">

                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/textInput_qr"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:inputType="number"
                            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                            android:textAlignment="center" />
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Did you figure this out? I ended up changing to a regular EditText and adding a setOnKeyListener

Comment: Try add `singleLine=true` at edittext XML